# How to refactor these callbacks in jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The codes are below:

```
<label>radio 1 </label>
<input type="radio" onchange="$('input2').show()" id="radio1" name="RadioGroup">
<label>radio 2 </label>
<input type="radio" onchange="$('input2').show()" id="radio2" name="RadioGroup">
<label>radio 3 </label>
<input type="radio" onchange="$('input2').hide()" id="radio3" name="RadioGroup">

<input type="text" id="input2">
```

There might be two drawbacks of these codes:

1. the jquery codes for `onchange` have to be written three times
2. the `onchange` codes will only be executed when I **click/change** one of the `radio`. In other words, these codes would **not** be executed when the **page is initialized**. For example, if the `radio3` is being checked when the page is initialized, the `input2` will still be displayed..

Comment: using inline jQuery must be some form of blasphemy.  You should be using unobtrusive JavaScript

Comment: For #2 you want to extract the logic out into either a declared function that has the logic or handler for a custom event.  Then you either call the function or trigger the event on page load.  Considering 1 & 2 together you may as well put all of the information in the same function.  Give the radios the same name and the inputs the same class.  Get the value of the radio element, hide all inputs with that class except for the proper one for the selected radio.

Comment: @MattWhipple Browsers that don't understand `onchange` will ignore it, so that's already unobtrusive; whether it's good practice is another thing.

Comment: @Jack part of unobtrusive JavaScript is the separation of the behavior from the markup, having inline event handlers breaks this idea.  jQuery's event binding is easy and flexible because it is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick jsfiddle that reorganizes this a bit.

1) assign a class to any of the radio buttons that show the input
2) assign another class to any radio button that hides the input
3) attach an event in the jQuery document.ready in a separate js file that manages the actions.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kw4gu/2/

HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>radio 1 </label>
<input type="radio" class="open" name="radioGroup" id="radio1">
<label>radio 2 </label>
<input type="radio" class="open" name="radioGroup"   id="radio2">
<label>radio 3 </label>
<input type="radio" class="close" name="radioGroup"   id="radio3">

<input type="text" id="input2">
```

​JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".open").on("change", function(event) {

        $('#input2').show();
    });

    $(".close").on("change", function(event) {

        $('#input2').hide();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Don't use "live" - it has been deprecated in jQuery. Use "on" instead.

Comment: thanks, edited, to use on :D

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set the event handlers via Javascript instead of bundling them in the HTML like that. Use a jquery selector to select the radio buttons and then add the events in a single place.

Doing things via Javascript also gives you more flexibility on when to initialize the code, how you run things, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple different ways, but it's fairly straightforward in jQuery. I've updated your HTML a bit (gave the two similar buttons a common class for easier selection AND I gave all buttons the same name so they are part of the same button group).

```
<label>radio 1 </label>
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" id="radio1" name="buttonGroup">
<label>radio 2 </label>
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" id="radio2" name="buttonGroup">
<label>radio 3 </label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="buttonGroup">

<input type="text" id="input2">​
```

Now, you have to write your selectors to hide or show the field depending on which button is being selected. That is shown here:

```
$(function() {
    $('#input2').hide();

    $('.radioButton').on('change', function() {
        $('#input2').show();
    });
    $('#radio3').on('change', function() {
        $('#input2').hide();
    });
});​
```

Note, I started off within `$('#input2').hide();` just to hide it initially, but I would do something like that in CSS normally.

In any case, you can see an example of this working at [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4YpdY/1/).